# How to handle: this request has no response data available

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest

I'm working on a web application that is dependent on responses based on various requests I send to an API and I would like to cater for a situation where there is no network access for the user in order to inform them to try again later. My only issue is that I am not getting any response from the back end when I have no connection, so I guess my question is; How do I inform the user that there is no response because of lack of connection?

Comment: Whenever you want to handle errors, you should take a look at [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) (server-side) or just check if the XHR response is empty on the client-side.

Comment: You can probably check the status code of the http request to the server. If it sends you a non 2xx range aqnswer, something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: Timeout.

You have to define a duration after which the connection is considered as down.

Then you can implement it either in php, depending on the connection method you are using or in javascript: Once the request is sent to the server, start a javascript timer that will display a error message if nothing happen before the timer reached out.